# How to push streamed diagnostic logs of Azure resources from EventHub to LogAnalyticWorkSpace using Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have streamed diagnostic logs from all the Azure resources in EventHub. I'm planning to use Azure Function to push the logs from EventHub to Log Analytic Workspace.

How can I use Azure function for pushing the logs to LogAnalytics ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a function in between instead of logging directly to a workspace?

Comment: I want to parse logs in azure function and push the parsed logs to Log Analytic workspace

Comment: what do you mean by parsing logs ? Could you please clarify your usecase ?

Comment: Can we directly push the streaming logs which have been collected  from EventHub to Log Analytic Workspace ?

Comment: This question Needs Clarity or Details, but seems to have been abandoned. I shall try to close it for now.

Answer (score 0):

To push Logs from EventHub to Log Analytic Workspace. I have tried to implement, Firstly, open your EventHub then Click on Diagnostic settings then Click on Add Diagnostic Setting:

[image]

Then follow below steps:

[image]

### Output

Then you open your LogAnalytics Workspace, Then Click on Logs and use kql query as below :

```
AzureActivity | where OperationNameValue contains "EVENTHUB"
```

[image]

Comment: By creating a  diagnostic setting on Eventhub, it will send the activity logs of EventHub to Log Analytic Workspace(LAW). But I need to push the azure resources streamed logs present in EventHub to LAW.

Comment: I thought of creating an azure function to push the streamed logs from EventHub to LAW. Is there any other easy way to push streamed logs ?